# Verifying whether a map is a polynomial ring automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

On pg.1, [this article](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf) talks about an automorphism $f:R[x_{1},x_{2}]\to R[x_{1},x_{2}]$ ($R$ is a ring) defined by
$$f(a)=a, \forall a\in R$$ $$f(x_{1})=x_{1}+x_{2}$$ $$f(x_{2})=x_{2}$$ 
An automorphism as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) is an isomorphism, which means it has to be surjective. But is this mapping really surjective? How is the element $x_{1}x_{2}$ mapped to, for instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $x_1 x_2 = (x_1 + x_2)x_2 - x_2 x_2 = f(x_1 x_2 - x_2^2)$. you've just got to show the map is surjective on generators. clearly $x_2$ is mapped to, and you can see how to map to $x_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that each of $R$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ lie in the image of $f$ (do you see why?). Clearly $R$ does, since $f(a) = a$ for every $a \in R$.

On the other hand, we see that $f(x_2) = x_2$ and $x_1 = f(x_1) - f(x_2) = f(x_1 - x_2)$. Hence, the map is surjective.

Now that we have pre-images for $x_1$ and $x_2$, do you see how to get a pre-image for $x_1 x_2$?

(Do keep in mind, though, that one also must check that $f$ is *injective*).

Comment: @T.Bongers- Could you also indicate how to check for injectivity. I figured the way to prove that is if $p_{1},p_{2}\in R[x_{1},x_{2}]$, then $f(p_{1})=f(p_{2})$ iff $p_{1}=p_{2}$. But I am not facing a lot of success in this. I tried proving the leading terms have to be different, but that too is turning out to be problematic.

Comment: I also tried: if an inverse exists, then the mapping is injective. Is $g=f^{-1}$ if $g(x_{2})=x_{2}, g(x_{1}+x_{2})=x_{1}$ and $g(a)=a$ where $a\in R$?

Comment: Define $g$ by $g(a) = a$ for $a \in R$, $g(x_1) = x_1 - x_2$ and $g(x_2) = x_2$. Then $(g \circ f)(a) = a$, $(g \circ f)(x_1) = g(x_1) + g(x_2) = x_1$, and $(g \circ f)(x_2) = x_2$. So $f$ has a left inverse, implying that it's injective. So, yes.